Copy keyframes from one action to another that doesn't have keyframes
I want to know if it is possible to copy/paste keyframes from boneA in actionA to boneA in actionB without creating new keyframes.
Here is the situation: I have a long list of actions for this animated game character. There was a change and I had to add a new bone to it. I need this new bone to have the same keyframes in most of the actions. I can copy the keyframes from one action, but I can only paste to another after setting new keyframes for all the animated properties.
Is there anyway I can paste the keyframes without doing that?
